# GNU nano "Error reading lock file ./.NetPay.cpp.swp: Not enough data read"

Tags: nano

I am currently programming on my mac on the Linux server and I ran into an issue. I don't know what I did to get this, and I just want my program back.

```
Error reading lock file ./.NetPay.cpp.swp: Not enough data read
```

Please help if you can!

**NB:** *(I am new to this, so if you have instructions on how to fix this problem, please dumb it down for me as best as you can!)*

[image: nano open with the error]

Comment: See the duplicate. `nano` text editor creates files to backup changes you make to original file. When those get corrupted, you get that error. Simply remove yhr .swp file